# Specifying number of decimal places in Python

Tags: python

When accepting user input with a decimal in Python I'm using:

```
#will input meal subtotal  
def input_meal():  
    mealPrice = input('Enter the meal subtotal: $')  
    mealPrice = float (mealPrice)  
    return mealPrice
```

which returns exactly what is entered - say $43.45
but when using that value to calculate and display tax I'm using:

```
#will calculate 6% tax  
def calc_tax(mealPrice):  
    tax = mealPrice*.06  
    return tax
```

which returns a display of $ 2.607 using

```
mealPrice = input_meal()
tax = calc_tax(mealPrice)
display_data(mealPrice, tax)
```

How can I set that to $2.61 instead?
Forgive me, I realize this is basic stuff but they don't call it Intro for nothing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

There's a few ways to do this depending on how you want to hold the value.

You can use basic string formatting, e.g

```
'Your Meal Price is %.2f' %  mealPrice
```

You can modify the `2` to whatever precision you need.

However, since you're dealing with money you should look into the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module which has a cool method named `quantize` which is exactly for working with monetary applications. You can use it like so:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN
mealPrice = Decimal(str(mealPrice)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

Note that the `rounding` attribute is purely optional as well.

Comment: ``%.2f' % mealPrice' worked beautifully! (I'll have to look further into the decimal module though - couldn't get it to work)
Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 for the decimal reference;  with floats, you'll get some surprising roundings (e.g., try a meal price of `0.25`).  But I don't think your decimal line works:  try `quantize(Decimal('0.01'))` instead of `quantize('.01')`.

Comment: @Mark Thanks! you're right, it doesn't. I fixed it up, plus it had a syntax error .. should have tested my code :)

Answer (score 13):

I'm astonished by the second number you mention (and confirm by your requested rounding) -- at first I thought my instinct for mental arithmetic was starting to fail me (I *am* getting older, after all, so that might be going the same way as my once-sharp memory!-)... but then I confirmed it hasn't, yet, by using, as I imagine you are, Python 3.1, and copying and pasting..:

```
>>> def input_meal():  
...     mealPrice = input('Enter the meal subtotal: $')  
...     mealPrice = float (mealPrice)  
...     return mealPrice  
... 
>>> def calc_tax(mealPrice):  
...     tax = mealPrice*.06  
...     return tax
... 
>>> m = input_meal()
Enter the meal subtotal: $34.45
>>> print(calc_tax(m))
2.067
>>>
```

...as expected -- yet, you say it instead "returns a display of $ 2.607"... which might be a typo, just swapping two digits, except that you then ask "How can I set that to $2.61 instead?" so it really seems you truly mean `2.607` (which might be rounded to 2.61 in various ways) and definitely not the arithmetically correct result, `2.067` (which at best might be rounded to 2.07... definitely *not* to 2.61 as you request).

I imagine you first had the typo occur in transcription, and then mentally computed the desired rounding from the falsified-by-typo `2.607` rather than the actual original result -- is that what happened?  It sure managed to confuse me for a while!-)

Anyway, to round a float to two decimal digits, simplest approach is the built-in function [round](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) with a second argument of `2`:

```
>>> round(2.067, 2)
2.07
>>> round(2.607, 2)
2.61
```

For numbers exactly equidistant between two possibilities, it rounds-to-even:

```
>>> round(2.605, 2)
2.6
>>> round(2.615, 2)
2.62
```

or, as the docs put it (exemplifying with the single-argument form of `round`, which rounds to the closest integer):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the
>   even choice (so, for example, both
>   round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and
>   round(1.5) is 2).

However, for computations on money, I second the recommendation, already given in other answers, to stick with what the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#module-decimal) module offers, instead of `float` numbers.

Comment: Just a nitpick: thanks to the usual binary floating-point problems, `2.605` and `2.615` aren't exactly equidistant between two possibilities;  so it's really just down to pure chance that your round examples look as though they're giving a 'round-half-to-even' result.  `round(2.635, 2)` gives `2.63`, for example.

IOW, I *third* the suggestion to try the decimal module if getting the rounding direction right for halfway cases is important. :)

BTW, in Python 2.x, `round` still rounds halfway cases away from zero, rather than to even.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the option using *round*

Answer (score 3):

To calculate tax, you could use `round` (after all, that's what the restaurant does):

```
def calc_tax(mealPrice):  
    tax = round(mealPrice*.06,2)
    return tax
```

To display the data, you could use a multi-line string, and the [string format method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
def display_data(mealPrice, tax):
    total=round(mealPrice+tax,2)
    print('''\
Your Meal Price is {m:=5.2f}
Tax                {x:=5.2f}
Total              {t:=5.2f}
'''.format(m=mealPrice,x=tax,t=total))
```

Note the format method was introduced in Python 2.6, for earlier versions you'll need to use old-style string interpolation `%`:

```
    print('''\
Your Meal Price is %5.2f
Tax                %5.2f
Total              %5.2f
'''%(mealPrice,tax,total))
```

Then

```
mealPrice=input_meal()
tax=calc_tax(mealPrice)
display_data(mealPrice,tax)
```

yields:

```
# Enter the meal subtotal: $43.45
# Your Meal Price is 43.45
# Tax                 2.61
# Total              46.06
```

Comment: Also works perfectly.  Does that differ significantly from   'Your Meal Price is %.2f' %  mealPrice'  ?

Comment: `%5.2f` would work in the same way (see above). I've started to use `format` in preparation for the port over to Python 3. But for this case, I haven't done anything with `format` that can't be done with string interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the code for `display_data`, but here's what you need to do:

```
print "$%0.02f" %amount
```

This is a [format specifier](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for the variable `amount`.

Since this is beginner topic, I won't get into [floating point rounding error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), but it's good to be aware that it exists.

Answer (score 2):

This standard library solution likely has not been mentioned because the question is so dated. While these answers may scale to the other use cases beyond currency where differing levels of decimals are required, it seems you need it for currency.

I recommend you use the standard library `locale.currency` object. It seems to have been created to address this problem of currency representation.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

locale.currency(1.23)
>>>'$1.23'
locale.currency(1.53251)
>>>'$1.23'
locale.currency(1)
>>>'$1.00'

locale.currency(mealPrice)
```

Currency generalizes to other countries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use round() function.

```
round(2.607) = 3
round(2.607,2) = 2.61
```