# How to add checking for more than 1dp

Tags: python, python-3.4

Id like to stop a decimal input from being more than 00.0  (1dp). 
So they input a number but i want it to 1dp as its percentage (such as 44.7% or 7.5%)
Here is the code:

```
while nameSave <=0 or nameSave >99:
        while True:
            try:
                nameSave = float(input("Enter % Savings (Between 1-99%): "))
                break
            except:
                print("Needs to be a number ")
```

Comment: Take a peek at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221654/specifying-number-of-decimal-places-in-python) This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
while nameSave <=0 or nameSave >99:
    while True:
        try:
            nameSave = float(input("Enter % Savings (Between 1-99%): "))
            check = str(nameSave)
            if (check[1] == '.' and len(check) > 3) or len(check) > 4:
                print("Needs to be precise to 1 decimal point")

            break
        except:
            print("Needs to be a number ")
```

Comment: I thought the same, what if they enter 2.75, that would be accepted since its 3 digits. (4 if you count the decimal point) I would like 2.75 to not be accepted. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: It should work now, but I think there are better solutions for that.