# How to set decimal places of string?

Tags: python-3.x

How to set a format of variable value for 5 decimal places and set to

```
pyautogui.typewrite("value")
```

?

I mean value should have 5 decimal places and then I need to put it in this format to command above. How to set format without printing?

```
import pyautogui
for i in 2:
pyautogui.click(169, 681)
pyautogui.doubleClick(474, 679)
pyautogui.typewrite(['backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace'])
value = -0.5 + (i - 1) * 0.00001
str(value)
pyautogui.typewrite("value")  # -0.5000
pyautogui.typewrite(['enter']
pyautogui.moveRel(474, 679, duration=0.2)
```

Thank you

Comment: This thread should [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221654/specifying-number-of-decimal-places-in-python)

Comment: I don't know even with your help. Is it necessary to convert `value` to string?

Comment: You already converted value to string using str(value), and to answer your question no it's not necessary to convert it to a string. you should be able to just say round(value, 5)